# How to generalized the formula in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to vary the condition for the n-th vector to cover a range of i-values (something like i=2:27).

```
N=51;
num =2; 
W = 3;
i = 2;

string1 = '[';
for n = num:-1:1
    string1 = [ string1 'a' num2str(n) ' '];
end
string1 = [ string1 '] = ndgrid(1:W);'];

string2 = 'ind = find(';
for n = 2:num
    string2 = [ string2 'a' num2str(n) '>=a' num2str(n-1) '&' ];
end

for n = 1:num
    string2 = [ string2 'a' num2str(n) '+'];
end
string2 = [ string2(1:end-1) '==i);' ];

string3 = 'C = [ ';
for n = 1:num
    string3 = [ string3 'a' num2str(n) '(ind) ' ];
end
string3 = [ string3 ']' ];
eval(string1);
eval(string2);
eval(string3);
```

Unfortunately, I have difficulties in understanding how this is a generalization of my initial construct.

Ultimately, I need the matrix p2 (which selects combinations of a1, a2 to an) in a probability analysis.

Comment: Please state your question more clearly and reduce your code to the absolute minimum to show the problem.

Comment: My question is this code is only for num=2 and i=2 but i need to do this code for i=1:17 and num=1:17.But i cannot make a for loop to do that.

Comment: Obscenely bad programming style. Avoid creating strings like this, then evaling them. There are other, far more efficient styles to use, as well as far easier to debug and read.

Comment: need suggestion how can i do this.

Comment: The original question was asked here, and abandoned, and username changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084833/how-to-calculate-the-value-within-a-for-loop-in-matlab

Comment: Is this the "knapsack" programming problem?  Some kind of explanation needs to be included with the code.

Comment: @Schorsch-i cannot understand ur comment.

Comment: @Schorsch-U can add ur answer here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084833/how-to-calculate-the-value-within-a-for-loop-in-matlab

Comment: @Schorsch-I really cant reopen the question.can u response on my email address?

Comment: @Schorsch-Please now you response my question because it is reopen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
N = 5; % number of columns, this was your a1 ... a5

W=3; % unchanged to first example in question
i=6; % unchanged to first example in question

% the following will create a matrix with N-1 columns
% because the last column is determined by the sum of the columns before it
% the a1 .. an-1 columns contains all possible permutations of 1:W
% (this code can be found on the internet)

for ii=1:N-1
    dset{1,ii}=1:W;
end

n=numel(dset);
a=cell(n,1);
[a{1:n}]=ndgrid(dset{end:-1:1});
a=reshape(cat(n+1,a{:}),[],n);
a=a(:,end:-1:1);

% next, we sort the rows ascending 
% because for you, 1-1-2 is the same as 1-2-1
% and after sorting, we pick the unique rows

a = unique(sort(a,2),'rows');

% next, we populate the last column
% and select those that match your criterion
% in a matrix p2n

p2n = [];

for ii=1:size(a,1)
    a(ii,N) = i - sum(a(ii,1:N-1));
    if(a(ii,N-1) <= a(ii,N) && a(ii,N)<=W)
        p2n=[p2n;a(ii,:)];
    end
end
```

See the comments in the code for explanations.

**EDIT**
If you want to vary `N`, `i` and `W`, use `for`-loops for example:

```
for N=2:4
    for i=2:27
        for W=3:7

        % post code starting at line 11 here
        % DO NOT DECLARE N, W, i inside the loops again

        % Also, introduce a cell to store all `p2n` matrices: 
        % place this inside the loop but below the code given above

        P2n{N,i,W} = p2n; 

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Showing error message-??? Undefined variable "r" or class "r".

Error in ==> com_all at 39
a=reshape(cat(n+1,r{:}),[],n);

Comment: This code is working for single N.But i need to run this code for example i=4 then N=2:4.How can i do this ?

Comment: @user2663126 please consider deleting your comments to the answer and to the question that are no longer needed now that the question is answered. that will keep it tidy.

Comment: @schorsch-your code is working only for single value of N.but i need to run this code for i=12 and N=4:12.i added the part that you mentioned on ur last comment but still its not working.Can you recheck ur code?

Comment: @user2663126 Last time I checked, the `for`-loop was indeed going through values from `N=2:4`. If you need different values for `N`, I suggest you get familiar with [`for`-loops in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/for.html). Also, storing `p2n` in a cell `P2n` with the indexing I used, will lead to empty cells for values not used in the loop. If I run the example above and check `P2n{2,2,3}` I get a value, just as I get one for `P2n{3,3,3}`. So the code **is** working for different values of `N`.